# Storing a text file in Firestore's text field removes line breaks

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store a CSV file in a text field inside Cloud Firestore. However Firestore is stripping out all line breaks and storing the entire CSV file as a single line. The [Firestore Data Types documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) does not say anything about a restriction on the type of characters that can be stored other than they should be UTF-8:

> Up to 1,048,487 bytes (1 MiB - 89 bytes). Only the first 1,500 bytes of the UTF-8 representation are considered by queries.

- Is there a documented restriction?
- If indeed line breaks can't be stored, what is the recommended alternative? Base64 encoding?

**Update**

The code roughly looks like this:

```
/**** Read CSV file ****/
let csvFileText;
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
    this.setCsvFileText(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);

//------ Wait for user to hit submit button ------

/**** Create order in Firestore ****/
const order = {
    csvFileText: csvFileText,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@gmail.com'
}

return this.db
    .collection('orders')
    .add(order)
    .then(docRef => docRef.id);
```

Just before calling Firestore, I can see that `order.csvFileText` is a nice CSV file with line breaks (in Chrome debugger). When I look at the value stored in Firestore (in the Firebase console), the line breaks are lost.

Comment: Please edit your question to illustrate how you're updating data, and what exactly you're observing that suggests the data is not the same on the way out as on the way in.

Comment: Question updated with code and description.

Comment: Are you sure that the console isn't just showing you an altered view of the data? What if you write code to query the document - does it come out the way you expect?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. Let me give it a shot. All I tried was to edit that field in the console and copy the data out.

Comment: Ok, confirmed that I can read the document with line breaks intact. So the console display was simply deceiving. Hope this is something that the Firebase team can fix. Thanks so much for your help! If you could add a short summary of your comments as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All data going in to and out of the database is preserved as-is.  What you're seeing is the fact that the Firebase console shows a simplified view of the data without carriage returns.  If this isn't good for your use case, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Pasting a string with newlines into the console doesn't preserve the newlines though?

Comment: @BradThomas The newlines are there.  You just can't see them in the console.  If you query for the string using the SDK, you will get the newline.

Comment: When I paste a string with newlines into the Console, save it there, and read that string with my app, it is displayed in my app without newlines though

Comment: @BradThomas It doesn't work in either direction.  You should use a script to populate the database with real data.  The console is just for poking around.

Comment: Ok gotcha. The newlines can be stored, just not with the console right now. Thank you